# Cannot install NodeJs on Linux Mint Vera

Tags: linux-mint

This is the command I executed (following the docs):

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash - &&sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And this is the error message that appeared:

> Your distribution, identified as "vera", is not currently supported, please contact NodeSource at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues if you think this is incorrect or would like your distribution to be considered for support

One potential workaround that I can think of is installing a nodejs version meant for the previous Mint release, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this [github](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/760) issue, I'd try doing the [manual installation](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/#debmanual).

Another options looking at the script. `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sudo -E bash -`  downloads a script from the internet and runs it.

Download the script this way: `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x > setup_19.x`. Now you have a new file called `setup_19.x`.

The script seems to have a check for your distro, called `check_alt()`. after the definition of that function, it's called for multiple distros.
one of them defines like so:

`check_alt "Linux Mint"     "vanessa"         "Ubuntu"        "jammy"`

meaning you might want to format it like so:

`check_alt "Linux Mint"     "vera"         "Ubuntu"        "jammy"`

Mint Vera seems to be based on Ubuntu Jammy so there's nothing to change there. So, just add the line I wrote above to the other lines with `check_alt` in there (you'll spot it), run the script, and finally run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AnotherSherlock happy to hear! Which method have you tried? Manual install or changing the script?

Comment: Changing the script. @sefsf

Comment: @AnotherSherlock oh ok, great!

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | sed -e 's/vanessa/vera/' | sudo -E bash -
```

**Description:**

Curl get the install script. In the script, we replace all occurrences of the word 'vanessa' with the word 'vera'. We hereby obtain installation nodejs permission for this Linux distribution. Next, the script is launched.